# Search in badges

Tags: discussion, badges, search

I wonder if there is a way to search in badges. I know that there are a lot of badges, so I can't go read them one after another. Is there a search option or something like that to get to the badge I'm searching for?

For example, if I wrote "answer" I would get a list of all the badges containing this word.

Right now if I write "answer" in the search field, it only searches the questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the badges page on the site you're interested in. The easiest way is to click the big Badges link in the top bar:

.[image]

When you get to that page, use Find in your browser (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) to find `answer` or `link` or whatever on the page. Here is an example for `bounty`:

[image]

You can also make the list shorter by filtering to gold, silver, or bronze:

[image]

Finally keep in mind that many badges just refer to **post** rather than specifically **question** or **answer**.

Comment: i dont want filter by bronze or silver or something i have seen this . i mean search through all badges by descriptions, if i write answer i get badge conatining the word answer . read my question

Comment: Yes, that is why I said **use Find in your browser** to do that once you are on the badge page

Comment: its better if there is some button or some search input or something like that. for all users can do it easily.

Comment: There are less than a hundred badges, the badge page describes them, and there isn't really another place the system could search other than the badge page, so I'm  not sure how you would word your feature request, but you can always ask.

Comment: For greater likelihood of a particular term turning up in a badge description, you might want to use the same strategy on [this question and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/167443).